# Sending an array as a query parameter to a rest WS (nullpointerException)

Tags: rest, playframework-2.0

I need to call a rest *web service in playframework 2* and I need to send a **query parameter** which is an **array**. In regular html I would send it like:

```
GET http://host.com?a=1&a=2&a=3
```

But when I do it when I try to do it with the playframework 2 WS api I do the next:

```
Map<String,String[]> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
paramMap.put("a",new String[]{"value1","value2"});

WS.WSRequestHolder holder = WS.url("http://host.com");

Set<String> keys = paramMap.keySet();
for (int i = 0; i < paramMap.get(key).length; i++)
{
    holder.setQueryParameter(key, paramMap.get(key)[i]);
}
```

And the first time that *setQueryParamater()* arrives, everything goes perfect but the second time I get a **NullPointerException** and *paramMap.get(key)[i]* is not null. Is this possible? is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be a bug in play-framework, but solved in 2.1 version.

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/360-bug-in-wsjava-setqueryparameter-leads-to-npe-when-adding-a-query-parameter-twice

Answer (score 0):

In regular html you *need to* dsend it like:

```
GET http://host.com?a=1&a=2&a=3
```

Using ampershand(&) to separate parameters in query string instead of comma(,)

Edit: Sorry forgot to type: Like ur trying to do within the loop you should not have fields with same name. You should change it as:

```
http://host.com?a1=value1&a2=value2
```

I don't know if this causes NullPointerException you face. But even if does not i suggest you change ur implementation to keep one value per field (key, value)

Comment: Oh! sorry, it's true, that's what i meant. Edited